# Is there a stripped down jQuery Mobile that works like jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I don't like jQuery Mobile for one reason and one reason only: the fact that you have to use their UI (or spend hours to customize it).

The question: is it possible to get a strip down version of jQuery Mobile to work exactly like how jQuery works where you can use any CSS, any HTML and add jQuery functionality to it without using any of their UI.  I want to be able to use jQuery Mobile functionality without any of their CSS/HTML.  I want to write my own CSS and HTML.

Comment: You are going to have to adhere to the structure of a jQuery Mobile page: `<div data-role="page"><div data-role="content"></div></div>` but other than that you can opt-out of any of the "enhancements" that jQuery Mobile makes to the DOM. I suggest reading the documentation for a better understanding of how to use the framework: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/

Comment: @Amir You say you don't want to use jQuery Mobile's UI. From what I understand, the entire *point* of jQuery Mobile is the UI. What parts of it do you want to keep that you can't find in jQuery 1.7?

Comment: Take a look at XUI.js http://xuijs.com/

Comment: @Jasper, mblase75 - I guess I thought jQuery Mobile would be something like jQuery where you can add to any site and use various functions to enhance the user experience.  So I was hoping something similar for mobile sites where we can include the jQuery mobile JS and enhance the user experience similar to what jQuery would do for a desktop website.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So go for it.

You are not tied to their UI.

It is merely a suggestion.

As long as your IDs and classes match their code everything should work just as well.

Comment: With jQuery i can use any ID and class and use that writing jQuery code.  I just want jQuery Mobile that works exactly like jQuery.  Specifically the events on mobile devices, like touch, swipe, etc.  I would love to be able to use those events on any ID or class I define.

Comment: This doesn't really explain how to do anything.

Comment: That's because the OP answered his own question. If he wants to write his own CSS and HTML for jQuery Mobile, he needs to... write his own CSS and HTML. There's a version of [ThemeRoller](http://jquerymobile.com/themeroller/) just for this.

Comment: I think the OP want to handle all his HTML and CSS the way he wants and hook with JQuery some function like Fading, adding attribute, and also mobile functionnality without having to use specifics CSS tag.

Comment: @mblase75 - I don't think you understand.  When we work with jQuery, we can write whatever html or css.  Then with jQuery we can .click() or .animate() etc..., but with jQuery Mobile, I can't just start of with a blank page and write my own html and start calling .click() or .animate().  That's what I'm saying.  ThemeRoller is not what I meant when saying "I want to write my own CSS/HTML".

Comment: Update - Started using jQuery Mobile and loving it.  Themeroller will help me a lot with customizing the colors and look.  I understand why jQuery Mobile is like this now.

Comment: Read this comment: you need to work a bit more. jQuery mobile is perfectly customizable, you're just being lazy (we all know the feeling).

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget jQM offers a Theme Roller as well

- http://jquerymobile.com/themeroller/

So making custom themes should be a little easier

I know in the Release Notes for RC1 they had decoupled jQM and were working on a Download Builder

- http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2011/09/29/jquery-mobile-1-0rc1-released/

> **Download builder: In the works**
>
> Now that we’ve decoupled most of the UI widgets, we’ve set the stage
>   for there to be a download builder. This will let you build a custom
>   version of jQuery Mobile to only include the parts you need. For
>   example, you could just use the core files to add Ajax-based
>   navigation with pushState and leverage some of the touch events and
>   other utilities with a very lightweight build (roughly 10k). Or, you
>   could add in specific UI widgets like form elements, listviews, etc.
>   to create an optimized build. We’re aiming to have a download builder
>   tool launch as part of 1.0 final in some form. We’re working on a
>   dependency map now for all the plugins to support this tool.

Not sure if this is release as of yet